# How does file inclusion work on pebble?

Tags: c, pebble-watch

I found [this very helpful example](https://github.com/rigel314/pebbleMenuExample) about MenuLayers and it works very well. In [this line](https://github.com/rigel314/pebbleMenuExample/blob/master/src/menuExample.c#L15) it is said that the method was defined in another file.

```
showDetail(cell_index); // Defined in detailView.c
```

As i compile and run, everything get´s called correctly. But im wondering how the compiler knows when to include this file?

I can see no include instruction, so my idea was that all files in the src/ folder will automatically be included. But if that is so, in which order?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the *compiler* or preprocessor (which handles the `#include` directive), it's the *linker* which does the "magic": The compiler writes special data in the object file, saying that the name `showDetail` is an external symbol, and then when the linker takes all source file it looks for the symbol `showDetail` in the other object files and write the correct output to the executable file.

Comment: That pretty much answers my Question. Maybe you can post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pebble SDK uses [waf](https://code.google.com/p/waf/) as its build tool. It is configured in the `wscript` file.

If you look at the `wscript` file of your Pebble project you will see the following lines:

```
def build(ctx):
    ctx.load('pebble_sdk')

    ctx.pbl_program(source=ctx.path.ant_glob('src/**/*.c'),
                    target='pebble-app.elf')
```

This tells the compiler to compile and link together all the ".c" files in `src/` and all of its sub-directories.